# How many were "deliberately" killed after Stalin's rule in Soviet Russia?

Tags: soviet-union

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_of_deaths_in_the_Soviet_Union_under_Joseph_Stalin#Total_number_of_victims), the historian Timothy D. Snyder argues that Stalin might have deliberately killed about 6 to 9 million people. Other historians estimate a much higher number of deaths due to Stalin's rule, including deaths of famines, which were deliberately caused by Stalin.

I'm not interested in the exact number of deaths caused by Stalin, what I am interested in is how many people were killed "deliberately" after Stalin's rule in Soviet Russia.

Gathering from the same Wikipedia article, the ways people were deliberately killed are the following:

- Executions
- Death through gulags
- Death through deportation
- Death through (intentionally created) hunger
- ...

I wonder how many were deliberately killed in these manners or others after Stalin's rule? I mean the time period of 1953 - 1989.

Comment: Do you mean "after" or "during"?

Comment: @fdb After. After 1953 till 1989

Comment: So you are comparing 29 years with 36?

Comment: @fdb I'm less interested in comparison, I'm more interested in the number of "deliberate" or "purposive" killing in the time after Stalin was ruling. I haven't found any numbers for deaths after Stalin's rule

Comment: I'm not convinced it's a great idea to lump together all killings by the post-Stalin Soviet state. The number would include some cases that would also have resulted in execution in other industrialized countries that have the death penalty, such as the US and China. It would also include people executed by the state for political crimes, which would be an extreme statistical rarity in the US. Wouldn't it be of more interest to separate out different categories, rather than lumping gangsters together with political dissidents?

Comment: China? Industrial country? In 1953? How being indistrial is connected to executions? Being industrial forgives executions? Have you heard about the Cultural Revolution in China? Are we in the kindergarten?

Comment: You have mixed principally different periods: 53-56 years, when Gulag system continued to exist, and 56-89, when repressions ceased to be a system and only people that did or said something against the system were repressed. Notice the difference: before 56 you could do NOTHING to guarantee that you won't be the target of repressions. In late 80-ties that was named the border between totalitarian and authoritarian regimes.

Comment: But really, I do not know how you want to count the victims. For example, due to her outspoken political views, which she refused to give off, my mother couldn't work since 1971. Till the end of USSR. So, we often were on the brim of simple hunger. But we were not in the worst possible situation. I personally knew one guy who died of hunger in 76 in Bukhara. Surely, many people, who had kolkhoz "pensions" equal to few dollars, died of hunger, too. But how can you count them? Mostly they were old or ill, their deaths were always declared as natural ones.

Comment: 1) Execution. Do you think that bandits, maniacs, rapists are innocent victims of Stalin? Start with the Bible. 10 commandments.
2) The Gulag is a colony. These are "easy" means. Colonies for prisoners can be found in any country. Even right now. What is the difference?
3) Deportation = resettlement. This is not a way of killing.
4) There was no artificial famine. It is a myth.
Your question is a consequence of Russophobic propaganda. Looking for false versions of a false theory?

Comment: A real dispute between my grandmother and her friend.
- We were starving!
- When?
- In young age! We were starving!
- You're just an old fool! We were not starving, we were losing weight! Because guys like slim girls!

Comment: @Konstantin AFAIU, the OP never claimed the victims to be innocent (nor otherwise). He is just asking for a count, not for moral jugement.

Comment: @BenCrowell You are right, it would be more interesting to have numbers of different categories. Can you provide these numbers?

Comment: @Konstantin As Evargalo said, I just asked for the count. Further, I cited a wikipedia article which states: "Many historians have suggested that Stalin was responsible for death total of around 20 million, citing much higher victim totals from executions, Gulag camps, deportations and other causes". Furthermore, is asking how many german civilians died during allied bombing a consequence of Allied-o-phobic propaganda? It's funny for me that asking questions is already a sign for some kind of phobia or propaganda.

Comment: Unlike you, I'm not funny. The history of my country is being rewritten before my eyes. This is monstrous. Monsters turn into angels, leaders turn into monsters.
You gave a provocative question.
Do you want a simple number? Good! In the book "Another Stalin" it was a figure of about 30 people. About 30 people were personally destroyed by Stalin.
Millions of repressed. Yes, innocent people were shot. But this was the law (the court, the emergency triple, etc.). Who accepted these monstrous laws? Party bosses, such as Khrushchev.

Comment: You are partly right ... Stalin is responsible ... Stop! Stalin bears 1/10 of the responsibility. Because Stalin was not the president. This was not the sole form of government. It is very convenient to write off all the evil for one person. Are you looking for the guilty? Who had the same authority as Stalin? Who controlled the punitive organs? Why do not you accuse these people? They were directly responsible. Why do not you notice the real guilty "Stalinist" repression?

Comment: In 1940, there were 40,000 murders in the USSR. Now in Russia, 40 thousand die on the roads in road accidents. The number of criminal murders more than death sentences in 1937.
Stalin's repressions in modern Russia ?!

Comment: @Konstantin You know the funny thing is that I didn't even ask for the numbers of people who are killed by Stalin. I asked for the number of people killed, AFTER THE TIME STALIN WAS RULING. AFTER. Further, I was citing some people in a wikipedia article. I wasn't making any statements at all. So, rather attacking me, why don't you go after the historians from which I got these statements? It seems to me, that Wikipedia is a bigger threat to you than I am to you.

Comment: You're right! I saw what I usually see.

Comment: However, I do not give up on my words. Your initial data is false.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the amnesties after Stalin death the only method of "deliberate killing" was execution by a court decision. The numbers of executed were kept secret but it was probably less than 1000 per year (by most estimates):

http://articles.latimes.com/1990-10-02/news/mn-1746_1_death-penalty
http://www.nytimes.com/1983/08/03/world/in-soviet-the-death-penalty-persists-without-any-debate.html

At the time of Stalin death there were millions of people in the camps, and certainly many of them died before the amnesties. But I suppose that after 1960 there were no "deliberate killings" except those executed by court decisions. 
Perhaps I should mention that certain crimes punishable by death in Soviet Union are not considered capital crimes nowadays, for example "currency speculation", and that some sentences were made by secret courts (in the cases of high treason).

EDIT. There were several occasional atrocities, like [Novocherkassk massacre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novocherkassk_massacre), or 
[abuse of psychiatry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_abuse_of_psychiatry_in_the_Soviet_Union) which can be qualified as deliberate killings, but there was nothing on the scale comparable with Stalin's times.

Comment: By way of comparison, simply in order to get a feeling for the orders of magnitude involved, the US has usually had something like 0.1 death penalty cases resulting in legal execution per year per million people https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_punishment_in_the_United_States#/media/File:Executions_in_the_United_States_from_1608_(new).png , while China has about 2. The post-Stalin Soviet figure seems to be roughly on the same order of magnitude as China's.

Comment: USSR 1937 - 200 million people - 2 million prisoners.
Russia 200x a year - 140 million people - 2 million prisoners.
Conclusion: either in Russia bloody repression right now, or "Stalin's repression" is a myth.
But in a hundred years in Wikipedia there will be tales of bloody repressions in Russia throughout the whole history ... Crazy house.

Comment: Mass deportations happened long after Stalin was dead, and had the silent objective to be rid of the deported population. Technically it may not have been deliberate killings, nobody personally pulled the trigger, but dumping thousands of people in summer clothes out of a train car in the Siberian winter with not even tools to build shelter has the exact same effect.

Comment: @jwenting : some sources for these massive post-1960 deportations ?

Comment: "dumping thousands of people in summer clothes out of a train car in the Siberian winter" - this is Fake News of the Goebbels/CIA Propaganda. "Americans" cut out the entire population of the continent and believe that the Russians are the same. If you want to justify your stupidity and cruelty - Ok. If you want to understand what really happened, do not eat garbage. The real story is simple and logical. But in order to understand the real story, one must read a lot of books. And never touch Wikipedia.

Comment: Several books on real history. These are rare books. And they were printed only in Russia in a small print run.
Igor Pykhalov "What are the scale of Stalin's repressions"

Comment: Sergey Kremlev "Beria, the best manager of the XX century."

Comment: Yuri Zhukov. "Other Stalin"

Comment: Where do you see the advertising of fascism? Where is the logic? Give the definition of fascism, Nazism and nationalism, please.